# Cost of Parameterization in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, optimization

Does Anybody know absolute or relative cost of forzed parameterization in SQL Server 2008?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of anything put out by Ms more than the guidelines from [Forced Parameterization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175037.aspx). If my opinion is of any value, from what i know about this process, the cost of changing the plan to be forced parametrized has a minimal impact on the overal cost of the query. As always, there are always a lot more details that can push the answer into the realms of 'it depends', like: complexitiy of the query, possible impact of parameter sniffing, posible loss of partition restrctions  etc etc, but you asked a very generic question.

You can read my reply at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608522/dynamically-created-sql-vs-parameters-in-sql-server/1608856#1608856 on an more detailed explanation on a related topic, why simple/forced parametrization is a far cry from actually using true parameterized queries.

Comment: i think this is the best answer that i will get, thx